# Data URL of mp4 video on safari not playing any video content

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

**I am trying to show mp4 video content on a html webpage, it works fine on Chrome but not playing on Safari.**

***Here is the code***

```
<video autoplay muted loop controls playsinline id='videoDataURL'></video>
<script>
var base64Data = '$base64encoded_video_content';// base64 encoded video content from data base php
        var binaryData = atob(base64Data);
        var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryData.length);
        var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++) {
          uint8Array[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'video/mp4' });

        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var video = document.getElementById('videoDataURL');
        video.src = blobUrl; // it gives https://websitename.com/2b71f214-<some_more_string>
      </script>
```

I have tried to add this attributes --
`preload="metadata" autoplay="" loop="" muted=""`

video with source and attributes

```
    <video id="video" class="video" >
            <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

none of them are working

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong in this and how to fix it
Thanks

Comment: It might simply be using a codec that Safari doesn't support ...?

Comment: "it gives..." and then you show a URL. Do you have a video, or a link to a video?

Comment: @Roy_In what happens if: After `video.src = blobUrl;` you also add a `video.load();` and a `video.play();`? Just in case Safari is more strict...

Comment: @ChrisHaas link to a video which we convert it into data url

Comment: @VC.One sure I will try it and let you know